# Upper right and lower right limits of the function at a point.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I am confused by the following.

**Question 1**. Does the right limit of the function at a point exist always in extended real line?

**Question 2**: If the first answer is "yes" then why do we introduce upper right and lower right limits of the function at a point? I mean what is the motivation for this? The motivation behind  introduction of the right limit and the left limit is obvious.

**Question 3**: If the first answer is "no" please give some example when upper right and lower right limits are different.

EDIT: I ask it because I read somewhere that the right limit (and the left limit) exists always in extended real line. But can not find the source and definitely may be I understood something uncorrectly.

[image]

Comment: For Question 1): Consider $f(x)=\sin \frac 1x,x\ne 0$ and see if $\lim_{x\to 0+} f(x)$ exists.

Comment: @Koro I see. Then what can we say about upper right and lower right limits of this function when $x\rightarrow 0^+$?

Comment: The upper right and lower right limits of the function mentioned in earlier comment would be $+1$ and $-1$ respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the right limit of the function at a point always exist in the extended real line?

No, right hand limit (RHL) or left hand limit (LHL) don't need to exist. To see an example: Consider the function $f:\mathbb R-\{0\}\to\mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=\sin\frac 1x$.
You may verify that for this function neither $\lim_{x\to 0+} f(x)$ nor $\lim_{x\to 0-} f(x)$ exists.

An example where upper right and lower right limits are not the same:

Consider $g:[1,5]\to \mathbb R$ defined as $$g(x)=\begin{cases}1; x\in \mathbb Q\cap[1,5]\\0; x\in (\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q)\cap[1,5]\end{cases}$$

Note that range $g=\{0,1\}$ and hence by definition for any $a\in [1,5)$, $\liminf_{x\to a+} g(x)=\sup\{\inf\{g(h): a\lt h\le a+\delta\}: (\delta\gt 0) \land (a+\delta\lt b) \}=\sup\{0\}=0$.

Similarly, $\limsup_{x\to a+}g(x)=1\ne 0=\liminf_{x\to a+} g(x)$.

Comment: Thank!!! Now I understand.

Comment: @Mokhmad-SalekhKhekhaev: Glad to be of help. You should also try to show that upper right and and lower right limits (as $x$ approaches $0$) of the function $x\mapsto \sin \frac 1x, x\ne 0$ are $+1$ and $-1$ respectively. :)

Comment: Yes. I thought about this after your comment. I look at the graph and got why it is true.

Comment: @Mokhmad-SalekhKhekhaev: Graph may aid you in visualizing this but that's not a proof. I meant that you should try to write a proof using the definitions of upper/lower right limits in OP. :)

Comment: We have $f(x)=\sin \frac 1x,x\ne 0$. For right lower limit we have $\liminf_{h\downarrow 0}f(x):=sup\{inf\{f(x)|x\in (0,0+\delta\}\}$. Now the question is "How I can find this limit?". I have a target value with the aid from the graph. It is "-1". So I can write $\liminf_{h\downarrow 0}f(x):=\sup\{inf\{f(x)\}\}= \sup \{-1\}=-1$. Is it finish the task for lower write limit or I must make some clarifications?:)

Comment: @Mokhmad-SalekhKhekhaev: Please note that you have written the definition of lower right limit in your comment wrongly ($\delta \gt 0$ is missing) and I think that to complete the proof, you should also justify how you got $-1$ inside "$\sup$".

Comment: I have a little question. About four Dini derivatives and one-side derivatives. We say that **right derivative** exists if there are exist **upper right and upper left** Dini derivatives exist? And we say that **left derivative** exists if there are exist **lower right and lower left** Dini derivatives exist?

Comment: I think I have to open new question

Comment: @Mokhmad-SalekhKhekhaev: We say that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ exists if upper and lower limits of  $f$ at $a$ exist (finitely) and are equal. So I think that we say right derivative exists if upper right and lower right derivatives exist and are equal.